# Layout API version naming

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't figure out how is this working:
If I made a folder named `layout-v11` is this going to apply to all api versions from v11 upwards or only to v11?
And second one can I make folder named `layout-v11-v14` to use this layout for only v11 and v14 API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suffix specifies the minimum version for which the resources will apply. v11 means v11 and up. v11 can be overridden by higher-level ones like v14.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after trying I have find out that it work `upwards`
for example if we named our folder `layout-v8`:

Device with api = **7** it will use default `layout` folder.

Device with api >= **8** it will use `layout-v8`

Now seems easy.
If I made mistake or there are some tricks - please write in comment.